# What can I do to set the value of a column in a new row in such a way that it have the same value of the auto increment primary key of the table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am absolutly new in **C#** (I came from Java) and I have the following problem

I have a method that execute an **INSERT** query to insert a new record into the table that is univocallu identify by an Id (the **primary key**)

So my table have some fields including: **Id** and **VulnerabilityAllertId**.

These two fields must have the same value.

At this time my method that perform the **INSERT** query work in this way:

I pass a **VulnsSmall** model object to the method and it create a new record in the table with each fields having the value of the related field in the model object

```
    public void insert(DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnSmall v) {

        _strSQL = "";
        string strSQLParametri = "";
        string query = "";

        System.Data.Common.DbCommand command;
        command = _connection.CreateCommand();

        // [VulnerabilityAlertId] insertion on the DB:
        if (v.VulnerabilityAlertId != null) {
            _strSQL = "INSERT INTO VulnerabilityAlertDocument ( [VulnerabilityAlertId] ";
            strSQLParametri = " VALUES (@VULNERABILITYALERTID ";
            addParameter(command, "@VULNERABILITYALERTID ", v.Id);
        }

        // [SourceId] insertion on the DB:
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(v.SourceId))
        {
            _strSQL += ",[SourceId] ";
            strSQLParametri += ", @SOURCEID ";
            addParameter(command, "@SOURCEID", v.SourceId);
        }

        .................................
        .................................
        .................................   

        // [Language] insertion on the DB:
        if (v.Language != null)
        {
            _strSQL += ",[Language] ";
            strSQLParametri += ", @LANGUAGE ";
            addParameter(command, "@LANGUAGE", v.Language);
        }


        query = _strSQL + " ) " + strSQLParametri + " );";
        command.CommandText = query;
        _executeNoQuery(command);

    }
```

My problem is that this code section is wrong:

```
        // [VulnerabilityAlertId] insertion on the DB:
        if (v.VulnerabilityAlertId != null) {
            _strSQL = "INSERT INTO VulnerabilityAlertDocument ( [VulnerabilityAlertId] ";
            strSQLParametri = " VALUES (@VULNERABILITYALERTID ";
            addParameter(command, "@VULNERABILITYALERTID ", v.Id);
        }
```

It is wrong because, in the database **VulnerabilityAlertDocument ** table the **[VulnerabilityAlertId]** column must have the same value of the **Id** primary key that is **auto increment**

In my previous code it use the value into **v.VulnerabilityAlertId** model field to set the **[VulnerabilityAlertId]** column value for my new row, so it have not the same value of the **Id** primary key column

What can I do to set the same value of the **[Id]** autoincrement column for the **[VulnerabilityAlertId]** column in my new row?

Comment: Not your answer, but if the `v.VulnerabilityAlertId` could be null you will have a lot of problems here

Answer (score 0):

If i get your query correctly,
you can make **changes at database level** 
by adding a *mirror column* to the primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE VulnerabilityAlertDocument
ADD mirror AS [Id] UNIQUE
```

and then you have a column which always replicate the value of primary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IDENT_CURRENT:

```
CREATE TABLE test_identity
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    letter nvarchar(1),
    value int DEFAULT(IDENT_CURRENT('test_identity'))
)

PRINT IDENT_CURRENT('test_identity')

INSERT INTO test_identity(letter) VALUES ('a')
INSERT INTO test_identity(letter) VALUES ('b')
INSERT INTO test_identity(letter) VALUES ('c')
INSERT INTO test_identity(letter) VALUES ('d')

SELECT * FROM test_identity

DROP TABLE test_identity
```