# How to automatically set the value of a not primary key column with the value of the primary key in an insert query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I am working on an **INSERT** query that insert a new row in a table named **VulnerabilityAlertDocument**

This table have 3 fields:

- **Id**: that is an **auto increment** int and it is my **PRIMARY KEY**
- **VulnerabilityAlertId**: this field is an int and **must have the same value of **Id** column
- **SourceId**: is a varchar(50) and contains some text.

Now my problem is how to do that the **VulnerabilityAlertId** have the same value of the **auto increment* Id value for this new record.

If I do something like:

```
INSERT INTO VulnerabilityAlertDocument 
       ( [VulnerabilityAlertId], [SourceId] ) 
VALUES 
       (4, 'TEST');
```

it create a new record in the table in whic the **Id** column value is not specify because it is auto increment, and the **VulnerabilityAlertId** value is 4

I need that in this query, the **VulnerabilityAlertId** value is automatically setted with the value of the **Id** value of the new row

What can I do to do it?

Comment: Do you want to achieve this with only a single query?
can you split it rather into 2 queries?

Comment: As per my knowledge, Either you have to write two queries or trigger for same. Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Will the value of `VulnerabilityAlertId` **ever** be different to `Id`? I am assuming (but uncertain) that you are wanting to set the "default" value here?

Comment: What's the difference between this question and [What can I do to set the value of a column in a new row in such a way that it have the same value of the auto increment primary key of the table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987489/what-can-i-do-to-set-the-value-of-a-column-in-a-new-row-in-such-a-way-that-it-ha)? Also, this smells like XY problem. **Why** would you need two columns always containing the same value?

Comment: simple make VulnerabilityAlertId as computed column only.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question is it like you want the `VulnerabilityAlertId` value automatically setted with the value of the Id column of the new row always?
If yes then you should alter the table definition and add `VulnerabilityAlertId` column as a persisted computed column as:

```
alter table VulnerabilityAlertDocument drop column VulnerabilityAlertId;
alter table VulnerabilityAlertDocument add VulnerabilityAlertId as id persisted;
```

by doing this there's no need to specify the values for `VulnerabilityAlertId` column as it will be computed every time a new row is inserted.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Why not just rename the Id column?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I'd skin this cat...

I would amend my table definition (apologies, can't think of a better field name right now):

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
   Id                         int identity(1,1) NOT NULL
 , SourceId                   varchar(50)           NULL
 , ActualVulnerabilityAlertId int                   NULL
 , VulnerabilityAlertId As Coalesce(ActualVulnerabilityAlertId, Id)
);
```

Essentially I have changed `VulnerabilityAlertId` to be a calculated field and added a new field to hold the "raw" data.

You can then populate the table like so:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (SourceId)
  VALUES ('TEST 1');

INSERT INTO your_table (SourceId)
  VALUES ('TEST 2');

INSERT INTO your_table (SourceId)
  VALUES ('TEST 3');

INSERT INTO your_table (SourceId, ActualVulnerabilityAlertId)
  VALUES ('TEST 4', 12345); -- Non-"default" value!
```

If you need to update a value then you need to refer to the `ActualVulnerabilityAlertId` field:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET    ActualVulnerabilityAlertId = 937
WHERE  SourceId = 'TEST 2';
```

Results:

```
SELECT Id
     , SourceId
     , ActualVulnerabilityAlertId
     , VulnerabilityAlertId
FROM   your_table
ORDER
    BY Id;

Id SourceId VulnerabilityAlertId ActualVulnerabilityAlertId
-- -------- -------------------- --------------------------
1  TEST 1   1                    NULL
2  TEST 2   937                  937
3  TEST 3   3                    NULL
4  TEST 4   12345                12345
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways..

1. If you can split this into multiple statements, use @@Identity after inserting the record to update the recently inserted row.

or
2. make use of below built-in sql server function.

`IDENT_CURRENT('table_name') + 1`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to populate VulnerabilityID with the newly created identity .

.then you have to `@@Idenity` to retrieve the **latest identity generated** and then send it to insert statement of **VulnerabilityiD**

**For ex:**

```
 declare @vulid int
```

`insert into tablename(params`) --> Normal insert statement that generates identity

**now, get that latest identity created by using**

`set @vulid=(select @@Identity)` -> newly generated identity is stored in this varaibale now

Insert this into table now..

```
 updatetablename set vulnerabilityid=@vulid;
```

**This will ensure that latest generated id is inserted as Vulnerabilityid**

Hope this helps..

Comment: I think he 'll need to make sure both calls are in the same transaction